# Trying to input data from separate sheet in Google Sheets using =Vlookup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, gs-vlookup

Hey im having this problem using Google sheets where i am trying to get data from a separate sheet and input that data into another.

http://i.gyazo.com/acafe4f159991bd0d1eaa9bc5c8e108d.png

This is the VLOOKUP that i am using however it does not seem to get any data from the response form 2.

The image for response form 2 is below:

http://i.gyazo.com/4ab62ba5c2b5d78a7716c2a094d7af22.png

Comment: check this link, i'm not sure if that is what you are trying to do: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943?hl=en

Comment: thanks for the reply and i have looked at that link before but it didnt really provide much information unfortunately, thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Have you tried making your own custom function with apps script? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions  you can call the sheet that contains the information https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String) and get the range of data

Comment: I havent actually, i might have to give it a go if i cant find a solution due to deadlines. Thank you for link could be useful

Comment: im not sure what you mean by excel tag?, are you referring to "=VLOOKUP" function

Comment: o right as in for this post, sorry i thought it related due to functions used in google sheets and excel are alike, Anyway guys ive fixed my problem which i shall Answer

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these, replacing 'ss' with the actual name of the 'source sheet' (the sheet where the data should be pulled from).

```
=index('ss'!C2:C, match(C2, 'ss'!D2:D, 0))
```

or:

```
=vlookup(C2, {'ss'!D2:D, 'ss'!C2:C}, 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for the help, i have realised what the problem was which is because the the unique identifier has to be on the very left of the table and so for my case the unique identifier is "MAC Address" so after i created a brand new form with the MAC address on the very left column it fixed the problem. I used the same VLOOKUP as shown in my screen shot above.

Comment: That is indeed the reason. However the index match (see below) should have worked, and also this vlookup =vlookup(C2, {'ss'!D2:D, 'ss'!C2:C}, 2, 0) should have worked.. but glad to hear the issue is solved...

Comment: ahhh thank you you solution is much appreciated, its funny because just as you had posted this i just figured found the reason why mine wasnt working. However i now want to create button of some sort using google app script so when pressed will configure all the rows, do you have any ideas that can push me in the right direction to implement this